# What are the implications of using a Dynamic Router versus a DSL choice in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

It appears that a [Dynamic Router](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html) can be used in much the same way as [choice](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) in a route. Furthermore, in the Java DSL `choice()` can be rather dynamic based on changing headers or properties in routes.

Are there guidelines for when either one should be used? Likewise, are there performance implications in using one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

in short...

- the `choice` is used to perform conditional logic from within a route
- the `dynamic router` is used to route messages to other routes/endpoints dynamically

that said, you can use the choice EIP to route to different endpoints based on content, but that endpoint list would be statically defined in the route.  If you need to determine the routing endpoints at runtime, use `dynamic router` or [recipient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)

performance characteristics should be similar, but are mostly determined by the Expression used to perform your content based routing (headers faster, xpath slower, etc)